# How do you remove N/A from radio button groups?

Tags: 7, entities

I have added a radio button to my content type and I have found that N/A was automatically put in as a selection.  How do I get rid of this?

Comment: I guess make it a required field.

Comment: ... that seams to work.  wow.  That seems too easy, yet obscure.  Did I miss a note or something?

Comment: Good to hear! that you got it workout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a list field mandatory, the N/A option automatically goes away

Also, if you allow multiple values, the radio dot elements automatically becomes checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I strive to reduce complexity in the systems I build.  Following is a CSS only solution.  Replace the example field machine names with yours.

```
#edit-field-history-of-prematurity-und > div:nth-child(1),
#edit-field-diagnosed-und > option:nth-child(1),
#edit-field-history-of-hypoxia-und > div:nth-child(1),
#edit-field-ekg-und > div:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```